# Unable to bind function to std::function<void()> when passing a std::move() object as a function argument

Tags: c++11, std-function, stdbind, stdmove

Trying to compile this following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional> 

void print_num(std::promise<bool>&& result, int i )
{
    std::cout << i << " " << '\n' ;
    result.set_value(true);
}

int main()
{
   std::promise<bool> Promise0;
   std::future<bool> Result0 = Promise0.get_future();      
   std::function<void()> f_display_31337 = std::bind(print_num, std::move(Promise0), 31337);

}
```

Getting the following error:

In function 'int main()': 15:90: error: conversion from 'std::_Bind_helper&&, int), std::promise, int>::type {aka std::_Bind, int))(std::promise&&, int)>}' to non-scalar type 'std::function' requested

I know it has something to do with the function argument std::promise&& and the need for std::move, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` returns object of unspecified type which holds moved `promise` (noncopyable object) as data member. `function` is wrapper for Callable object, one of requirement of instance of `function` is to make the copy of stored Callable, in your case object returned from `bind` cannot be passed into function, because the copy cannot be made due to `promise` as data member.

You should use `auto` to deduce type of bind's result.

```
void print_num(std::promise<bool>& result, int i )
{
    std::cout << i << " " << '\n' ;
    result.set_value(true);
}

int main()
{
   std::promise<bool> Promise0;
   std::future<bool> Result0 = Promise0.get_future();      

   auto obj = std::bind(print_num, std::move(Promise0), 31337);
   obj();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a `move`-capturing lambda instead of a `std::bind`.

```
int main()
{
   std::promise<bool> Promise0;
   std::future<bool> Result0 = Promise0.get_future();      
   std::function<void()> f_display_31337 =
      [Promise0 = std::move(Promise0)] mutable
      { print_num(std::move(Promise0), 31337); };
}
```

The only drawback is that you need `c++14` enabled to compile this code.